# How do I use scope object within http service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need to make a http request depeendent upon the response of a json object. I have the specific string in the $scope.id object. My code is this

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/flat.json", {"key": "value"})
  .then(function (response) {$scope.id = response.data.id;});
});
```

I want to add another http request that would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1/{{id}}
```

I have tried everything that I can think of to generate this request, but i either get "undefined" variable or the script fails to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double brackets are reserved for the view. When working with javascript, you can simply use string concatenation to create your url.

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $http) {
  var path = 'theendoftheurl'

  $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/" + path , {"key": "value"})
  .then(function (response) {$scope.id = response.data.id;});
});
```

Edit: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to do something along these lines:

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/flat.json" , {"key": "value"})
      .then(function (response) {
         $http.post("http://127.0.0.1/" + response.data.id, {})
         .then(function (secondResponse) {
           //secondResponse is the data you're looking for
         });
      });
    });
```